# jsfiddle angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/basickarl/g8e8c13b/7/

The jsfiddle above doesn't seem to be working, what am I missing?

The following works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/

html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a data-ng-click="clickHere()">Click here!</a>
    <a onclick="alert('trololol')">Click here!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.clickHere = function () {
    alert('yeehaw!');
  };
};
```

Comment: 1. Declare angular module first.
2. Declare angular controller.
See docs for more details

Comment: I can open the link..

Comment: You really need to read the documentation if you don't see what's wrong here. It's really basic stuff.

Comment: Take about jumping the gun...

Comment: i can see jsfiddle that you have provided is working fine

Comment: @KarlMorrison, The link that you provided has older version of angular, that must have module intialiser inside. I don't know much about angular but if you link the version 1.1,1 then you must see

Comment: @Rahul So https://jsfiddle.net/basickarl/g8e8c13b/7/ is working for you?

Comment: @Manoz There we go! Post an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @KarlMorrison, I can't post answer until I've a solid proof of module initialiser :P

Comment: @Manoz I changed the version to 1.1.1 and it worked! In other words, you figured out what the issue was!

Comment: @KarlMorrison, Exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Manoz pointed out the two versions of Angularjs were different in jsfiddle. As this was a jsfiddle question and not a angularjs specific question.